# How can I tell ffmpeg to start to write on file as soon as it detects some motion?

Tags: ffmpeg

A little background. I am recording a stream from a camera (using `rtsp` protocol) and I'd like to save on the disk not the whole input stream but only some excerpts after a motion is detected.
The "basic" command I'm using is something like:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://{my_camera_address}/ -movflags +frag_keyframe+separate_moof+omit_tfhd_offset+empty_moov -acodec aac -vcodec h264 output.mp4
```

I recently add the `-movflags` option to achieve a sort of realtime, that is I can read the video file while is't been written by ffmpeg.
A user suggested [in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/984841/ffmpeg-remove-parts-without-motion) to add a filter to ffmpeg command in order to grab only the frames where a motion is detected, they used this option:

```
-vf select=gt(scene\,0.05),setpts=N/(25*TB)
```

But it has some incompatibility with the `-vcodec copy` option, although this is not a big issue.

My question is: is it possibile to use the filter (or another option) just to trigger the file writing? For example, I save a 5 minutes video after a motion-detection is triggered.

Comment: [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) is better suited for this kind of task.